# NameError: name 'Rem_Val' is not defined

Tags: python

I am a complete beginner to Python and was trying to create a program that asks user if he/she wants to remove a specific number from the predefined list I created.

```
Error - NameError: name 'Rem_Val' is not defined.
```

MY_Code:-

```
list_1 = [8, 3, 7]
print("This is List_1: ")
print(list_1)
Modify = input("Do you wish to modify the list? Y/N: ")
if Modify == 'Y' :
    remove = input("do you wish to remove something: ")
    if remove == 'Y' :
        Rem_Val = input("Enter the number you want to remove: ")
        list_1.remove(Rem_Val)
        print(list_1)
    elif remove == 'N' :
        print("Thank you for using this")
    else :
        print("Please answer in Y/N format \n Y= Yes, N=No")
elif Modify == 'N' :
     print("Thank you for using this")
else :
    print("Please answer in Y/N format \n Y= Yes, N=No")
```

Comment: ```Rem_Val``` is defined only if  ```if Modify=="Y"``` evaluates to True or you entered ```Y```

Comment: The output of input() is a string hence you need to convert it to int using `int(input())`. Furthermore, it is always a good idea to check if the element you want to delete exits in the list. `if Rem_Val in list_1:` then remove otherwise remove() will throw an error

Comment: The code should not generate this error: **Error - NameError: name 'Rem_Val' is not defined.**

Comment: Post the entire traceback.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code should not be `NameError`. Rather it's a `Value error`.

It is because the *input you take is in `string` format and you are attempting to remove a string from the list*. Eg. the user *wants to remove `3` but the code tries to remove `"3"` so throws a value error*.

Try **doing this to your code**:

- replace the line 8 by: `Rem_Val = int(input("Enter the number you want to remove: "))`

Now it should work fine.

Hope it helped!